# Subdomain sign in with Rails 4 and Devise 3.1.0

Tags: ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, subdomain

UPDATE --

I would recommend skipping direct to answer section -- goal of this was to allow multiple subdomains, each of which would have their own users/registrants.  A registrant could register on multiple subdomains, however each subdomain is treated independently and unassociated with the others.

I feel this questions is still in need of a better answer so please contribute to it.

===============

ORIGINAL POST --

Help please --

scenario --
My site is used by :teams, each of which has :users. Im trying to enable :users to log in via the :team subdomain.  (unique USER index keys are :email and :team_id -- the subdomain is part of a separate TEAM model that im trying to associate by :team_id in the user model during signin.)

TEAM MODEL

```
has_many :users
```

USER MODEL

```
devise request_keys: [:team_id]
belongs_to :team

def self.find_for_authentication(warden_conditions)
  where(:email => warden_conditions[:email], :team_id => warden_conditions[:team_id]).first
end
```

this is per the new instruction on devise wiki: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Scope-login-to-subdomain

APPLICATION CONTROLLER

I use before_action to set the team based on subdomain
I also add the strong params the "lazy" way for team_id  / devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) << :team_id

DEVISE SESSIONS NEW VIEW (For USERS)

I feel dirty doing this, but I have a hidden team_id input field

AND THE ERROR DUMP `NoMethodError undefined method team_id`

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 111.0.0.1 at 2013-09-13 13:08:09 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"LONG TOKEN HERE=", "user"=>{"email"=>"user@site.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "team_id"=>"16", "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  [1m[35mTeam Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."subdomain" = 'teamname' LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 119ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `team_id' for #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x007ffe950c2150>):
  devise (3.1.0) lib/devise/strategies/authenticatable.rb:142:in `block in request_values'
  devise (3.1.0) lib/devise/strategies/authenticatable.rb:142:in `map'
  devise (3.1.0) lib/devise/strategies/authenticatable.rb:142:in `request_values'
  devise (3.1.0) lib/devise/strategies/authenticatable.rb:122:in `with_authentication_hash'
  devise (3.1.0) lib/devise/strategies/authenticatable.rb:71:in `valid_for_params_auth?'
  devise (3.1.0) lib/devise/strategies/authenticatable.rb:16:in `valid?'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:351:in `block in _run_strategies_for'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:349:in `each'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:349:in `_run_strategies_for'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:319:in `_perform_authentication'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:127:in `authenticate!'
  devise (3.1.0) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:15:in `create'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:463:in `_run__412684316733059520__process_action__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:44:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__1066722413265567725__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  /Users/Home/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:145:in `handle'
  /Users/Home/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:99:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in start'
  /Users/Home/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:96:in `block (2 levels) in start'
  /Users/Home/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:86:in `each'
  /Users/Home/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:86:in `block in start'
  /Users/Home/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:66:in `loop'
  /Users/Home/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:66:in `start'
  /Users/Home/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:13:in `run'
  /Users/Home/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/bin/nack_worker:4:in `<main>'
```

Help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how i resolved --

I followed the instructions here exactly: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Scope-login-to-subdomain

To use these instructions i added the subdomain column to the users table (creating a lot of duplicate subdomains since each team has_many users).

Then in my Team controller when i update a team subdomain it also creates a query to gather all the users associated with the team to update their subdomain values as well.  Not the ideal fix but works well enough.

UPDATE

I hope someone finds a better way -- in mean time i'll make a small addition to this.  in order for the same email to work across multiple subdomains you need to add the below in your user model. Otherwise the same email will only be registered for 1 subdomain and any registrations on other subdomains will give you the email is already registered error.

```
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :scope => :subdomain
```

For this to work you need to remove :validatable from the devise options in your user model and create your own custom validations for email and passwords.

Comment: Yikes, I'm not a fan of that type of denormalization, but I haven't found a better way myself.

Comment: I'm following the same wiki article using Rails 4 and Mongoid but the `find_for_authentication` method doesn't even seem to be getting called.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to add column "subdomain" in DB-table. For example in my case I need provide authentication from "www" only for clients, and from "account" only for partners.

```
def self.find_for_authentication(conditions)
  subdomain = conditions.delete(:subdomain)
  if user = super
    case subdomain
    when 'www'
      user.client? ? user : nil
    when 'account'
      user.partner? ? user : nil
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

I guess this approach more simple.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is actually a bug related to a change in the way ActionDispatch::Request works.

Devise seems to be assuming that if it calls a key on the request hash it will get nil if the value doesn't exist and will get the value otherwise.

It attempts to access the request with .send which doesn't seem to work in the current version of rails.  If you patch devise like so:

```
diff --git a/lib/devise/strategies/authenticatable.rb b/lib/devise/strategies/authenticatable.rb
index 13249e8..df28fc9 100644
--- a/lib/devise/strategies/authenticatable.rb
+++ b/lib/devise/strategies/authenticatable.rb
@@ -148,7 +148,7 @@ module Devise

       def request_values
         keys = request_keys.respond_to?(:keys) ? request_keys.keys : request_keys
-        values = keys.map { |k| self.request.send(k) }
+        values = keys.map { |k| self.request[k] }
         Hash[keys.zip(values)]
       end
```

it seems to work fine.

Edit:  I wrote up a partial patch with a few more details here:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/3965